# ng-include gets commented out

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

So in my angular view I have this:

```
<div id="submenu" ng-include="'/submenu.html'" ></div>
```

But when I visit the page, the HTML part is:

```
<!-- ngInclude : '/submenu.html' -->
```

I put this line of code in other pages and it renders correctly. Only on one page it gets commented out.

What should I do, how can I fix this? I never saw this bug before.

Thanks

**edit**

I just checked and the code does not even perform a `GET` for this particular html file.

**edit**

I just remove the complex parts out of the age and now is just

```
<div id="submenu" ng-include="'submenu.html'" ></div>

<div id="anothersubmenu" ng-include="'anothersubmenu.html'" ></div>
```

and no one of these files render, they both get commented out. My controller looks normal. I view this on Chrome 49.0.2623.87 m. All the included files have the same id , everywhere I include them. All the files are in the same folder.

I dont know is there a limit on the `ng-include`?

Thanks

Comment: Best guess is the path isn't working and is returning 404 when request made for that template. Check browser dev tools network and see what happens with that request

Comment: @charlietfl I just checked and the code does not even performs a GET for this particular html file. I am lost now

Comment: So what else is different in this view than other ones that do work?

Comment: it would be great if you add a jsFiddle also if submenu is in same folder then please try <div id="submenu" ng-include="'submenu.html'" ></div> or <ng-include src="submenu.html"/>

Comment: It may be a comment restricted directive...

Comment: @AmanuelBogale What is this? How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: @Rahul I tried what you said and nothing worked. Also I cannot se t a fiddle because the files are complicated.

Comment: @charlietfl That is the crazy thing, nothing is different. The structure iis the same except the names of the `ids` change ad in one file I have a form and in the other I have a `div` instead of a form.

Comment: @charlietfl Check an update in my post if you want. Thanks.

Comment: @Rahul Check an update in my post if you want. Thanks.

Comment: No real reason shown that it shouldn't work especially since you say it works elsewhere

Comment: @slevin did you find any workaround? I am also having same issue. Already stole one day of my life.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scenario but I created the ngInclude element using
`angular.compile` and I also got
 `<!-- ngInclude : '/file.html' -->`

and I did not see any requests going out from my browser to get the file

Finally I resolved the issue using the 
`scope.$apply()`

The digest cycle had to happen before the actual including can take place.

hope it helps :)